# Changing window.location to redirect to another path causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, url, path

I have a simple asp .NET project in visual studio 2022 which I am using for basic html and JavaScript.
My project is a Hangman game with two html pages so far.
Each page has a button to get to the other page:

```
<button class="sideMenu" onclick="load()">New Game</button>
<button class="sideMenu" onclick="leaderBoard()">Leader Board</button>
```

the functions `load()` and `leaderboard()` that are launched when the buttons are clicked should redirect to the correct path using: `location.href = "/path"`

the problem is when I use this, every time I launch either one of the pages it runs into an infinite loop and keeps reloading itself until I get this error in the developer tools (I'm using chrome):

`play.js:90 Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/1038223. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection`

I tried some of the options (that don't include Jquery) I saw here: [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage/506004#506004) but they all cause the same problem.

these are my functions:

the load function: which loads a new game

```
function load() {
  location.href='/index.html'
  mistakes = 1;
  guess = 0;
  guessWord = [];
  keyboard = document.getElementById("keyboard")
  keyboard.innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      keyboard.innerHTML += "<button style='width:50px; height:50px; margin:5px;'class='letter' id='" + letters[i] + "' onclick='show(this)'>" + letters[i] + "</button>";
  }
  num = Math.round(Math.random() * (words.length - 1))
  word = words[num]

  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      guessWord[i] = " ";
  }
  screen = document.getElementById("screen")
  screen.innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      screen.innerHTML += "<div class='text' id='text " + i + "'> </div>"
  }
  document.getElementById("tries").innerHTML = "guesses: " + guess + ", mistakes: " +(mistakes-1);}
```

and the leaderboard function that shows the leaderboard:

```
function leaderBoard() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/scores.html')
    board = document.getElementById("board")
    if (scores.length < 1) {
        board.innerHTML = "NO SCORES FOUND"
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            board.innerHTML += "</ br> player: " + scores[i][0] + " word: " + scores[i][0] + + "guesses: " + scores[i][2] + " mistakes: " + scores[i][3];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use different navigation approaches in the both functions which isnt good.
Use `windows.history.pushState()` to change your url or your `router`.
`window.addEventListener("popstate", ...)` - react to your navigation here if you use `pushState()`

Also don't forget server site URL handling.